# GWT Hyperlink strange behavior - redirecting to http://localhost:8080/#

Tags: java, gwt

Okay, this is very strange.

All I am having is a `Hyperlink` in my menu:

```
Hyperlink eventCalendar= new Hyperlink("Eventkalender", "eventCalendar=" + store.getId());
```

and I am listening to the `ValueChangeEvent` in the `MainViewPresenter`. Please notice that I am not doing anything. Right before the creation of the listener I am setting a `SimplePanel` to be the display for the `ActivityManager`:

```
App.activityManager.setDisplay(this.mainView.getMainContentContainer());

History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String historyToken = event.getValue();
        GWT.log("onValueChange() historyToken " + historyToken);
    }
});
```

But if I click the link what happens is this:

First, for the blink of an eye I can see the browser URL change to

```
http://localhost:8080/#eventCalendar=1
```

but it changes immediately back to

```
http://localhost:8080/#
```

which causes my landing page to get loaded inside the `SimplePanel` which I declared as display (see above).

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this behavior because this does not make sense to me? Why does the URL get changed again? Am I using `History` or `Hyperlink` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your `PlaceHistoryMapper` returns `null` for the `eventCalendar=1` token, so it's replaced with the *default place* you gave to the `PlaceHistoryHandler`. If you're using `GWT.create()` based on `PlaceTokenizer`s, with a factory and/or `@WithTokenizers`, that means either you don't have a `PlaceTokenizer` for the empty-string prefix (`@Prefix("")`), or that one tokenizer returns `null`.

That being said, you probably should rather try to use places directly rather than going through the *history*. That means using a `ClickHandler` on some widget and calling `PlaceController#goTo` with the appropriate place. Ideally, that widget would be an `Anchor` whose *href* is computed from the result of `getToken` from your `PlaceHistoryMapper` with the given place (how the *href* actually looks depends on your  `Historian`; if you stick to the default behavior, then just prepend a `#` to the returned token).

Comment: Awesome! I made it a lot simpler following your advice. Thanks Thomas, as always! :)